# Get file name only (without extension and directory) from file path

Tags: python, operating-system, filenames, filepath

What I have:

```
import os
import ntpath

def fetch_name(filepath):
    return os.path.splitext(ntpath.basename(filepath))[0]

a = u'E:\That is some string over here\news_20.03_07.30_10 .m2t'
b = u'E:\And here is some string too\Logo_TimeBuffer.m2t.mpg'

fetch_name(a)
>>u'That is some string over here\news_20.03_07.30_10 ' # wrong!
fetch_name(b)
>>u'Logo_TimeBuffer.m2t' # wrong!
```

What I need:

```
fetch_name(a)
>>u'news_20.03_07.30_10 '
fetch_name(b)
>>u'Logo_TimeBuffer'
```

Comment: Use raw strings for Windows file names, as the backslashes can be converted into other things...; as in r'E:\That is some string over here\news_20.03_07.30_10 .m2t'

Comment: @EvertW I actually can't. The strings are in Unicode array

Comment: How exactly do you want to differentiate between a file extension and a normal `.`? Do you want to treat all three-character suffixes delimited by `.` as extensions?

Comment: @merlin2011 well exactly, I don't want to differentiate between it. A library should do this work for me -)

Comment: What I mean is, how is a library supposed to tell your intent? Why is `30_10` not a reasonable file extension? No library will read your mind unless you give it **some** guidance about what you consider to be an extension and what you consider to be just dots followed by letters.

Comment: @merlin2011 yep, I get it. It's about fixed and officially-known extension names I guess. For example `.m2t.mpg` is definitely extension, `.bla.mpg` is definitely not.

Comment: Your code works exactly as it should. In example a, the \n is not treated as a backslash character because it is a newline character. In example b, the extension is .mpg, which is properly removed. A file can never have more than one extension, or an extension containing a period.

Comment: @aspect_mkn8rd, Then you already have your solution. :) Just download or create a list of extensions that you consider official, and strip any suffix off your filename that is inside that list. By the way, I will write a program tomorrow that uses `.bla.mpg` as an extension. :P

Comment: okay, seems like I get all the situation clearly. Now can you please post these last two comments as answers? I wanna give you two guys rep for your effort and end the question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works exactly as it should. In example a, the \n is not treated as a backslash character because it is a newline character. In example b, the extension is .mpg, which is properly removed. A file can never have more than one extension, or an extension containing a period.

To only get the bit before the first period, you could use `ntpath.basename(filepath).split('.')[0]`, but this is probably NOT what you want as it is perfectly legal for filenames to contain periods.